# What is the canonical antonym for platform-agnostic when referring to software in computing?

Tags: architecture, computer-science, terminology, platform

Google defines **platform-agnostic** as:

> Denoting or relating to hardware or software that is compatible with many types of platforms or operating systems.
>
> `"many common file formats (JPEG, MP3, etc.) are platform-agnostic"`

and [**TechTarget**](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/agnostic) defines it (from an IT context) as:

> The ability of something to function without “knowing” the underlying details of a system that it is working within.

I tend to use the term **platform-dependent** or **cross-platform** as an antonym for **platform-agnostic**, but most definitions for these terms seem to imply a `hardware` context or give a definition opposite to **platform-independent**.

When referring to **software**, is *platform-dependent* a viable antonym for *platform-agnostic* for describing an application that only runs on a subset of **known** platforms *(e.g. operating system, devices, environments, etc.)* or is there a more appropriate computing term, such as **platform-gnostic** or **platform-specific**, to convey this?

Comment: Platform dependent would swing my vote, once you start coding dependency on specific architecture you make yourself platform dependent.  Cross-platform itself can be tricky if you care about where the dependence is met; though -- but I think you are safe with that word.

Comment: @Kaylus – that's what I tend to use for the same reasons. This might be a stretch, but depending on the context, if the undertone for a piece of software being *agnostic* is that it was designed *not knowing* the underlying system/dependencies, then maybe **platform-specific** or even **platform-known**, would be appropriate as well.

Comment: Platform-reverant?

Comment: Both "platform-dependent" and "platform-specific" convey the meaning you are searching for - "NOT platform-agnostic". Additional term that you can use albeit with a slightly tangential meaning is "vendor locked".